# TortoiseHg not prompting when I push multiple heads

Tags: push, tortoisehg

If I have a branch which now has two heads TortoiseHg used to prompt and prevent me from pushing two heads to the remote server. Now however, it just pushes them to the remote server. I have looked in the settings, but no options jumped out at me for bringing the prompt back.

Running TortoiseHg version 2.10.1, Mercurial version 2.8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option **Force push or pull (override safety checks, --force)** was ticked on my local repository.

This option was some what hidden, I could only find it by hitting the synchronize button which would bring up a new pane, and then it was under options.

Comment: It's sounds like you're talking about Toroisehg, which isn't part of Mercurial.  Mercurial doesn't have a GUI and there's nothing to 'tick'.  Maybe correct your title and tags to help future searchers?

Comment: Fair point - I always refer to it as Mercurial for some reason.

Comment: No worries TortoiseHG is simultaneously the best and worst thing that's happened to Mercurial, but it's definitely not part-of.  Some of the defaults those guys pick are bonkers! :)